# How can i use a function with "variable" constants in scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

how can i use "variable" constants in scipy.optimize functions? I am trying to create an iterative optimisation algorithm, which updates certain parameters in the objective function after each optimisation run.

to use a very simple example of what i want to do:

```
from scipy import optimize as opt

def f(x, R):
    return R * (x[0]**2 + x[1]**3)

R = 0.1 # initial R value
y = []
y.append([2,2]) # initial point

for i in range(0,10):
    y.append(opt.fmin(f, y[i])) # how can i include 'R' in this line??
    R = some_function_to_update_R(R)
```

any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:**
would it help to re-declare the objective function each time i optimise? so make the loop look like this instead?

```
for i in range(0,10):
    def f_temp(x_temp):
        return f(x_temp,R)
    y.append(opt.fmin(f_temp, y[i]))
    R = some_function_to_update_R(R)
```

or is there some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmin` supports an optional `args` argument, representing a tuple of additional arguments to be passed to the function you're trying to optimize:

```
y.append(opt.fmin(f, y[i], args=(R,)))
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) for `fmin`; you should get into the habit of checking the documentation when you want to figure out how to do something.

Comment: NOTE: Answers which suggest links to documentation should be STRICTLY left as comments. I urge the user to DELETE the last part of their answer or add it as a comment. It is against SO guidelines to suggest the user read the documentation as part of the answer.

Comment: @HamishGibson: Are you just trolling? Pointing users to documentation is totally fine. An answer that *just* links to the docs is link-only, which is discouraged, but this answer isn't link-only.